# How do I pipe the output string produced by readFile "filename.txt" to Haskell's words function as an argument?

Tags: haskell, readfile, ghci

from the `ghci>` prompt, I would like to **readFile** "filename.text" and pass the produced string as an argument to the **words** function to convert sentences to wordlists.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can execute your pure function (words) "inside" the IO monad returned by readFile.

```
readFile :: FilePath -> IO String
```

and

```
words :: String -> [String]
```

so you can simply do

```
fmap words $ readFile "filename.txt"
```

which has the type IO [String]. If you do this in ghci (which is itself "inside" of an IO monad) you will get the word list displayed.

EDIT:

If you want to apply multiple transformations you may want to cleanly separate the pure part (based on @Davislor's solution from comments):

```
readFile "filename.txt" >>= (return . sort . words) >>= mapM_ putStrLn
```

The `return` here just lift to IO, you could simply replace `return` with `mapM_ putStrLn` instead (sorter, but less clean distinction).

Another solutions may be applicative style:

```
sort <$> words <$> readFile "filename.txt"  >>= mapM_ putStrLn
```

or using do notation (imperative style):

```
do ; f <- readFile  "filename.txt"; let out = sort (words f) in  mapM_ putStrLn out
```

(which is ugly because I used `;` instead of newline) or simply (less imperatively :) :

```
do ; f <- readFile "filename.txt";  mapM_ putStrLn $ sort $ words f
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @goteguru

Comment: To complete the procedure, I would like to then apply -sort- and -mapM_ putStrLn- to stack the words alphabetically. Outside the IO monad I can seamlessly compose or nest these functions to accomplish this – any idea if this can be written inside the IO monad?

Comment: @LuqmanMalik `fmap (mapM_ putStrLn . sort . words) $ readFile "filename.txt"`. The `fmap` raises a function that works on ordinary data into one that works on data wrapped inside a monad. You could also bind with `readFile "filename.txt" >>= (mapM_ putStrLn . sort . words)` or use `do` notation.

Comment: @Davislor thanks for your notes – I had just returned to terminal and made some progress with `fmap sort $ fmap words $ readFile "wordlist.txt"`. Now, your first line only jumped to prompt on next line without printing anything to screen, but the second one worked like a charm...

Comment: @LuqmanMalik That’s because I goofed on the first one. Applying `mapM_ putStrLn` inside `fmap` gets you an `IO` object wrapped inside another `IO` object. You need to bind the input operation to the output operation instead. That works on the data inside and gives you another `IO` object as the result. Sorry.

Comment: One other thing that works, and might be clearer, is to `fmap (map putStrLn)` to get a list of `IO` objects that depends on an earlier `IO` operation, then  bind with `>>= sequence_` to execute them.

Comment: @LuqmanMalik If you want to chain your functions like that you might be interested in import Control.Applicative which gives you <$>.  `sort <$> words <$> readFile "filename.txt"` might be clearer. (IO is also instance of Applicative not just Monad)